# stochastic variable constant on atoms = measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, F, P)$ be a probability space, let $P_1,...,P_n$ be a partition of $\Omega$, let $F_0,...,F_n$ be a filtration of $F$, and let $P_t = \{ \text{atoms of } \ F_t\}$.

I don't understand the following sentence:

A random variable $X$ is $F_t$ measurable if it is constant on elements of $P_t$.

What does it mean for a random variable to be constant on a partition? And why does this guarantee measurability?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $X$ is not constant on the atom $A\in P_t$ of $F_t$. Then assume it can take the two distinguished values $x$ and $y$ on $A$. Since $X$ is measurable, $X^{-1}({x}) \in F_t$ holds. Therewith by basic properties of a sigma-algebra $X^{-1}({x}) \cap A \in F_t$ must hold. But since $A$ is an atom $A= X^{-1}({x}) \cap A$ which is a contradiction to the assumption $\{X=y\} \cap A \neq \emptyset$ (a.k.a. $X$ takes the value $y$ on $A$).